# Can x86 bit run on x32 platform and x64 platform?

Tags: visual-studio, x86, 64-bit, 32-bit

I created a program, but during development i create the project using x64 in visual studio. So the program was able to run successfully with the dsn in the 64 bit computer. but when i try to install the same program to 32 bit computer the program would not work and the dsn setup failed.

So i was wondering can i use x86 bit to setup the project, so that it will be able to run on both computer platform.

Comment: On Windows, certainly. A 32 bit Windows program can run on both 32 bit and 64 bit Windows. But a 64 bit program can not run on 32 bit Windows, as you already found out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a x86 application will run on either 32-bit or 64-bit computers

Comment: Well, technically, running a 32-bit application on a 64-bit version of Windows requires the WOW64 subsystem, which is an optional component (at least on server versions).